# Editing nested image in CKEditor widget doesn't work

Tags: image, widget, ckeditor

I'm using my own plugin providing widgets for the CKEditor. I'm not able to edit images in editables.

It's no problem to add an image. The editor shows it.

But if I want to edit one, the dialog fields (like URL) are empty. I'm using the default image plugin (no image2 widget).

Is there something I have to do for supporting this feature?

I added an example of my plugin. I'm using it in a drupal web portal in combination with the drupal ckeditor module.

```
// Register our custom "section" widget plugin with CKEditor.
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('section', {
    requires : 'widget',
    init : function(editor) {


        // Register the widget.
        editor.widgets.add('example', {
            template : '<section class="example"><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 editable-left"></div><div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center editable-middle"></div><div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 editable-right"></div></div></div></section>',
            allowedContent : 'section(!example)',
            editables : {
                left : {
                    selector : '.editable-left',
                },
                middle : {
                    selector : '.editable-middle',
                },
                right : {
                    selector : '.editable-right',
                },
            },
            upcast : function(element) {
                if (element.name == 'section' && element.hasClass('example')) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Could you create a sample? I've just checked on https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/widget/dev/nestedwidgets.html (with small changes to load the image plugin) and everything works fine.

Comment: Today, I tried the devlopment version and it works. Afterwards I tried a 4.4.7 full instead of using a CDN 4.4.7 and the error occurs again. Did something change in the development version concerning my problem? What's the difference?

Comment: There are no tickets related to widgets or the image plugin in [4.4.8](http://dev.ckeditor.com/query?group=status&milestone=CKEditor+4.4.8) so it seems that nothing related to these topic should have changed since 4.4.7. You can check out previous versions (there are proper tags for each) and see what happens.